# The method ...... is undefined for the type

Tags: java, polimorfismo

Por alguna razon estoy obteniendo este error:

> **The method SportCar(String, String, String, String) is undefined for the type Vehicles**

Estoy trabajando con polimorfismo en java, cuento con un archivo **Main** el cual importa un package llamado **vhcls**, el cual cuenta con una **superclase** llamada **vehicles** y una subclase llamada **SportCar** la cual hereda todas las características de la clase **vehicles**.
Mi intención es que dependiendo de el método que se utilice pueda utilizar el método de la subclase o la superclase.

Aquí tienen el código:

**Archivo Main**

```
import vhcls.*;

class Main {
    public static void main ( String[] args){
        Vehicles myVehicle = new Vehicles();
        String m = "XDF259";
        String mod = "CRV";
        String br = "Honda";
        myVehicle.vehicle( m, mod, br );
        System.out.println( myVehicle.getAllInf()  );

        Vehicles myCamaro;
        myCamaro = new SportCar( );
        String mm = "XLT123";
        String modd = "Camaro";
        String brr = "Chrysler";
        String yy = "2020";
        myCamaro.SportCar( mm, modd, brr, yy );
        System.out.println( myCamaro.getAllInf() );
    };
};
```

**Archivo Vehicles**

```
package vhcls;

public class Vehicles {
    String lPlate;
    String model;
    String brand;
    String year;

public void vehicle (String lPlate, String model, String brand) {
    this.lPlate = lPlate;
    this.model = model;
    this.brand = brand;
}
public void vehicle (String lPlate, String model, String brand, String year ) {
    this.lPlate = lPlate;
    this.model = model;
    this.brand = brand;
    this.year = year;
}
public String getLplate (){
    return lPlate;
}
public String getmodel() {
    return model;
}
public String getBrand(){
    return brand;
}
public String getAllInf(){
    return brand + " " + model + " " + lPlate;
}
}
```

**Archivo SportCart**

```
package vhcls;

public class SportCar extends Vehicles {
    String year;

public SportCar(){

};
public SportCar (String lPlate, String model, String brand, String year ) {
    super( lPlate, model, brand );
    this.year = year;
};
public int getyear(){
    return year;
}
public String getAllInf(){
    return brand + " " + model + " " + lPlate + " " + year;
}
}
```

Espero puedan ayudarme ya que he revisado en otros foros pero no he logrado dar con el motivo del error.

Comment: SportCar no es un metodo, es el constructor.. solo se llama cuando se construye la clase...

Comment: He hecho un cambio, al crear el objeto le he pasado los parametros necesarios:       

        Vehicles myCamaro;
        String mm = "XLT123";
        String modd = "Camaro";
        String brr = "Chrysler";
        String yy = "2020";
        myCamaro = new SportCar( mm, modd, brr, yy );

Pero ahora obtengo este error: 
The constructor Vehicles(String, String, String) is undefined at vhcls.SportCar.<init>(SportCar.java:13) at Main.main(Main.java:18)

Comment: Debes inicializar myCamaro como :   SportCar myCamaro; @Antuanct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simplemente tienes que aplicar el concepto de constructores múltiples. <s>Y, en el caso de `SportCar` tienes que evitar poner un constructor vacío.</s> Para poder crear instancias vacías tanto de `Vechicles` como de `SportCar`, tienes que poner en ambos un constructor vacío.

Otro error que tienes es en `year`, debería ser del tipo `int` en todas partes. En una parte lo declaras como  `int` y en otras lo pasas como `String`.

Luego, cuando crees los objetos, desde `new` le pasas directamente los valores que le corresponden y Java sabrá en base a eso qué constructor llamar.

En el segundo ejemplo que usas en el `main` te quiero señalar que si `SportCar` extiende de `Vehicle` no necesitas crear primero un `Vehicle` y luego pasarlo a  `SportCar`, lo creas como `SportCar` directamente, que para eso es la herencia.

Otra cosa que debes estandarizar es el nombre de los constructores, que siempre se llaman como la clase, y nunca se declaran como `void`. Tú los estabas declarando como `vehicles` con `v` minúscula.

Hay más problemas de incongruencia en tu modelo. Si observas bien, la propiedad `year` no sirve para diferenciar un vehículo normal de un vehículo de deporte. El constructor que usas para `myCamaro` ya existe en la clase `Vehicles`. Pensemos en una propiedad que tendría un `SportCar` que no tendría `Vehicle`. Digamos, que corre en un circuito o algo así.

Si aplicamos lo dicho el código quedaría así:

## `Vehicles`

```
public class Vehicles {
    String lPlate;
    String model;
    String brand;
    int year;

    public  Vehicles () {

    }

    public  Vehicles (String lPlate, String model, String brand) {
        this.lPlate = lPlate;
        this.model = model;
        this.brand = brand;

    }

    public Vehicles (String lPlate, String model, String brand, int year ) {
        this.lPlate = lPlate;
        this.model = model;
        this.brand = brand;
        this.year = year;
    }

    public String getLplate (){
        return lPlate;
    }

    public String getmodel() {
        return model;
    }

    public String getBrand(){
        return brand;
    }

    public String getYear(){
        return year;
    }

    public String getAllInf(){
        return brand + " " + model + " " + lPlate + " " + year;
    }

}
```

## `SportCar`

```
public class SportCar extends Vehicles {
    String circuito;

    public  SportCar () {

    }

    public SportCar (String lPlate, String model, String brand, int year, String circuito ) {
        super( lPlate, model, brand, year );
        this.circuito = circuito;
    };
    public int getCircuito(){
        return this.circuito;
    }
    public String getAllInf(){
        return brand + " " + model + " " + lPlate + " " + year +  " " + circuito;
    }
}
```

## Prueba

Observa cómo cambia la creación de los objetos, y todo se simplifica

```
public static void main(String args[])
{

    String m = "XDF259";
    String mod = "CRV";
    String br = "Honda";
    Vehicles myVehicle= new Vehicles( m, mod, br );
    System.out.println( myVehicle.getAllInf()  );

    String mm = "XLT123";
    String modd = "Camaro";
    String brr = "Chrysler";
    int yy = 2020;
    String circuito="F1";
    SportCar myCamaro= new SportCar( mm, modd, brr, yy, circuito);
    System.out.println(myCamaro.getAllInf());       
}
```

**Salida:**

```
Honda CRV XDF259
Chrysler Camaro XLT123 2020 F1
```

Comment: Gracias por tu ayuda. Con ello pude solucionar el problema.

Comment: @Antuanct me alegro. No obstante, revisa de nuevo la respuesta. Analizando detenidamente el modelo se aprecia que la propiedad `year` no sirve para diferenciar un `Vehicle` de un `SportCar`, pues debe haber una propiedad en  `SportCar` que no tenga `Vehicle`, para justificar la herencia. He puesto un ejemplo con una propiedad `circuito`. El problema en tu código es que el año es una propiedad que existe también en `Vehicles`.

Comment: Correcto, revisare nuevamente. Gracias por tu ayuda.

Answer (score 0):

deberias pasarle los datos en el constructor a la hora de crear el objeto SportCar

```
Vehicles myCamaro;
String mm = "XLT123";
String modd = "Camaro";
String brr = "Chrysler";
String yy = "2020";
myCamaro = new SportCar(mm, modd, brr, yy);
System.out.println( myCamaro.getAllInf() );
```

Comment: Hola, gracias por tu respuesta DaniDekk, 
Despues de hacer la correccion obtengo este error:

The constructor Vehicles(String, String, String) is undefined

        at vhcls.SportCar.<init>(SportCar.java:13)
        at Main.main(Main.java:18)

¿Que crees que pueda ser el nuevo error?

Comment: Eso es porque el nombre del metodo constructor debe ser igual que el de la clase, y en tu clase Vehicles no es asi. Cambia el nombre de los 2 metodos y luego en el Main haz lo mismo que con SportCar. Un saludo

Comment: Disculpa soy un poco nuevo en Java jaja, podrás explicarme exactamente que debo de hacer, disculpa la molestia.

Comment: jajjaja en la clase `Vehicles` debes llamar a sus 2 constructores igual, es decir `public void Vehicles (String lPlate, String model, String brand)` y `public void Vehicles (String lPlate, String model, String brand, String year )`, no `vehicle`

Comment: Gracias compañero. Fue de gran ayuda tu comentario.

Answer (score 0):

Como comenta @gbianchi:

> SportCar() no es un metodo, es el constructor.. solo se llama cuando se
>   construye la clase...

Por lo tanto llama ese constructor de la clase `SportCar`, el cual es usado para inicialiar la clase.

```
class Main {
    public static void main ( String[] args){
        Vehicles myVehicle = new Vehicles();
        String m = "XDF259";
        String mod = "CRV";
        String br = "Honda";
        myVehicle.vehicle( m, mod, br );
        System.out.println( myVehicle.getAllInf()  );

        //Vehicles myCamaro;
        SportCar myCamaro;
        //myCamaro = new SportCar( );
        String mm = "XLT123";
        String modd = "Camaro";
        String brr = "Chrysler";
        String yy = "2020";
        //myCamaro.SportCar( mm, modd, brr, yy );

        //* Inicializa constructor.
        myCamaro = new SportCar(mm, modd, brr, yy  );

        System.out.println( myCamaro.getAllInf() );
    };
};
```